# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

This error only happens when I do ipconfig. Dir and mkdir all seem to work!
First part is the program which would send the commands and the other one, the second one the one which connects to it.

```
import socket
import json
from sys import exit

class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Connection received from " + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def reliable_recieve(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
        return json.loads(json_data.decode())

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
        return self.reliable_recieve()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")
            print(command)
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            print(result)

my_listener = Listener("127.0.0.1", 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

Here is the program which connects to it:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import json
from sys import exit

class Connect:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_recieve(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(1024).decode()
        return json.loads(json_data)

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def execute_sys_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.getoutput(command)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_recieve()
            if command[0] == "exit":
                self.connection.close()
                exit()
            command_result = self.execute_sys_command(command)
            self.reliable_send(command_result)
        self.connection.close()

my_connection = Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444)
my_connection.run()
```

I don't know why this is happening, it doesn't make sense. All I can think of is that the error is ocurring at the return of the result of the command. I think this because it doesn't have anything different than dir or mkdir such as spaces or the way it's being encoded. So probably it's at the return.

Comment: If I'd have to guess, your `ipconfig` JSON data is probably larger than 1024 bytes so when you try to parse it - it breaks. Collect all the JSON data from your socket before parsing.

Comment: How do I do so?

Comment: You can do a `while True: ...` loop around your `self.connection.recv(1024)` code and concatenate the results until there is no more data left - at which point you can decode it and then parse the enclosed JSON. Or, for a more robust approach, check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50664122/7553525) and ignore the #4/#5 step as you're not adding any payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed `self.connection.recv(1024)` to a bigger number, thus accepting more bytes. The problem was, as mentioned by @zwer, that the output of the command of "ipconfig" was bigger than 1024 bytes.